# Linux command to get time in milliseconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

How can I get time in milliseconds in a Bash shell script?

Comment: `date +%s.%N` would give you nanoseconds, can you work with that?

Comment: @Wrikken This is not quite portable though.

Comment: date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S%3N" - 
Generally i use this command to get the fulldate and unique time till milli seconds to create the temporary file names in unix bash script. If your system is not able to cope up milli seconds you can go to micro or nano seconds using 3 to 6 and 9 respectively.

Comment: Try `date -Ins`

Comment: @CamiloMartin Why is this not portable?

Answer (score 459, accepted):

`date +%s%N` returns the number of seconds + current nanoseconds.

Therefore, `echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))` is what you need.

Example:

```
$ echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
1535546718115
```

`date +%s` returns the number of seconds since the epoch, if that's useful.

Comment: doesn't work on Mac OS, since `%N` is not supported by `date`

Comment: Question is asking for Linux command. @alper's answer works fine for date command with [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). GNUtize your OSX: [Install and Use GNU Command Line Tools on Mac OS X](http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/)

Comment: `date +%s%3N` is faster (based in @michael-defort's answer)

Comment: @caligari I'm not sure... Benchmarking several options in parallel (granted, not TOO strictly) gave me this: http://pastebin.com/ZFdVWN7h. Frankly, I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: On OSX you need to install the GNU version of date as part of `coreutils` using MacPorts or Homebrew - then use the `gdate` command. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804966/date-command-does-not-follow-linux-specifications-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: Although date +%s%3N seems to be easier or better, but using it in some other offset calculation caused the timestamp to be reduced by 1 millisecond! But this solution worked perfect with offset calculation

Comment: Perhaps something should be said about the actual time resolution? E.g., on a typical PC, will it typically be better than 16.666 ms (1/60 second) or not? Or better than some other (very common) characteristic feature of the underlying hardware?

Answer (score 544):

- `date +"%T.%N"` returns the current time with nanoseconds.

  ```
  06:46:41.431857000
  ```
- `date +"%T.%6N"` returns the current time with nanoseconds rounded to the first 6 digits, which is microseconds.

  ```
  06:47:07.183172
  ```
- `date +"%T.%3N"` returns the current time with nanoseconds rounded to the first 3 digits, which is milliseconds.

  ```
  06:47:42.773
  ```

In general, every field of the `date` command's format can be given an optional field width.

Comment: date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S%3N" for milli seconds.

Answer (score 133):

Nano is 10<sup>−9</sup> and milli 10<sup>−3</sup>. Hence, we can use the three first characters of nanoseconds to get the milliseconds:

```
date +%s%3N
```

From `man date`:

> **%N**     nanoseconds (000000000..999999999)
>
> **%s**     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

Source: Server Fault's *[How do I get the current Unix time in milliseconds in Bash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/151109/how-do-i-get-the-current-unix-time-in-milliseconds-in-bash/588705#588705)*.

Answer (score 76):

On OS X, where `date` does not support the `%N` flag, I recommend installing `coreutils` using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29). This will give you access to a command called `gdate` that will behave as `date` does on Linux systems.

```
brew install coreutils
```

For a more "native" experience, you can always add this to your `.bash_aliases`:

```
alias date='gdate'
```

Then execute

```
$ date +%s%N
```

Comment: This may have changed since this was posted. I don't recall installing coreutils and `date +%s%3N` works with no issue (Mar 2024).

Answer (score 29):

Here is a portable hack for Linux for getting time in milliseconds:

```
#!/bin/sh
read up rest </proc/uptime; t1="${up%.*}${up#*.}"
sleep 3    # your command
read up rest </proc/uptime; t2="${up%.*}${up#*.}"

millisec=$(( 10*(t2-t1) ))
echo $millisec
```

The output is:

```
3010
```

This is a very cheap operation, which works with shell internals and procfs.

Comment: I have now idea why I didn't find this sooner. This should be the accepted and perfect answer. I believed for so long there was no way to get sub-second accurate time in a posix shell (without involving a slow interpreter or hoping for date with %N support).

Answer (score 22):

## Pure bash solution

Since `bash` 5.0 ([released on 7 Jan 2019](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2019-01/msg00010.html)) you can use the built-in variable `EPOCHREALTIME` which contains the seconds since the epoch, including decimal places  down to micro-second (μs) precision (`echo $EPOCHREALTIME` prints something like `1547624774.371210` in English, or `1547624774,371210` in German, French, etc.). By removing the decimal separator and the last three places we get milliseconds:

Either use

```
(( t = ${EPOCHREALTIME/[^0-9]/} / 1000 ))
```

or

```
t=${EPOCHREALTIME/[^0-9]/} # remove the decimal separator (s → µs)
t=${t%???}                 # remove the last three digits (µs → ms)
```

Either way `t` will be something like `1547624774371`.

Comment: FYI the decimal separator is localized, so on my system in French, I'm getting `1695071065,749507`. You can force a period with `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for the hint. Very good point! I found `LC_ALL` to be complicated here, because we either have to use it in a subshell (which complicates setting `t`) or restore it manually. Both are not ideal. But I found a short general solution and updated the answer.

Answer (score 15):

The other answers are probably sufficient in most cases but I thought I'd add my two cents as I ran into a problem on a [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) system.

The system in question did not support the `%N` format option and doesn't have no Python or Perl interpreter.

After much head scratching, we (thanks Dave!) came up with this:

```
adjtimex | awk '/(time.tv_sec|time.tv_usec):/ { printf("%06d", $2) }'
```

It extracts the seconds and microseconds from the output of `adjtimex` (normally used to set options for the system clock) and prints them without new lines (so they get glued together). Note that the microseconds field has to be pre-padded with zeros, but this doesn't affect the seconds field which is longer than six digits anyway. From this it should be trivial to convert microseconds to milliseconds.

If you need a trailing new line (maybe because it looks better) then try

```
adjtimex | awk '/(time.tv_sec|time.tv_usec):/ { printf("%06d", $2) }' && printf "\n"
```

Also note that this requires `adjtimex` and `awk` to be available. If not then with BusyBox you can point to them locally with:

```
ln -s /bin/busybox ./adjtimex
ln -s /bin/busybox ./awk
```

And then call the above as

```
./adjtimex | ./awk '/(time.tv_sec|time.tv_usec):/ { printf("%06d", $2) }'
```

Or of course you could put them in your `PATH`

EDIT:

The above worked on my BusyBox device. On Ubuntu I tried the same thing and realised that `adjtimex` has different versions. On Ubuntu this worked to output the time in seconds with decimal places to microseconds (including a trailing new line)

```
sudo apt-get install adjtimex
adjtimex -p | awk '/raw time:/ { print $6 }'
```

I wouldn't do this on Ubuntu though. I would use `date +%s%N`

Comment: Wow, great alternative! Indeed your command works, but I don't have a clue why. Where do I find a documentation for the awk command?! How in hell did you find out how to build the string to extract the desired information out of the adjtimex output?

Comment: If there is a possiblity to compile Busybox yourself, enabling "CONFIG_FEATURE_DATE_NANO" would be another approach.

Answer (score 11):

`date` command didnt provide milli seconds on OS X, so used an alias from python

```
millis(){  python -c "import time; print(int(time.time()*1000))"; }
```

OR

```
alias millis='python -c "import time; print(int(time.time()*1000))"'
```

---

EDIT: following the comment from @CharlesDuffy.
Forking any child process takes extra time.

```
$ time date +%s%N
1597103627N
date +%s%N  0.00s user 0.00s system 63% cpu 0.006 total
```

[Python is still improving it's VM start time](https://bugs.python.org/issue34296), and it is not as fast as ahead-of-time compiled code (such as `date`).

On my machine, it took about 30ms - 60ms (that is 5x-10x of 6ms taken by `date`)

```
$ time python -c "import time; print(int(time.time()*1000))"
1597103899460
python -c "import time; print(int(time.time()*1000))"  0.03s user 0.01s system 83% cpu 0.053 total
```

I figured `awk` is lightweight than `python`, so `awk` takes in the range of 6ms to 12ms (i.e. 1x to 2x of date):

```
$ time awk '@load "time"; BEGIN{print int(1000 * gettimeofday())}'
1597103729525
awk '@load "time"; BEGIN{print int(1000 * gettimeofday())}'  0.00s user 0.00s system 74% cpu 0.010 total
```

Comment: ...however, once you've `fork()`ed off a separate process, `exec`ed your Python interpreter, let it load its libraries / otherwise initialize, write its result, and exit, that result will no longer be accurate.

Answer (score 7):

To show date with time and time-zone

> date +"%d-%m-%Y %T.%N %Z"

Output : 22-04-2020 18:01:35.970289239 IST

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add to [Alper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/command-to-get-time-in-milliseconds/16548827#16548827) what I had to do to get this stuff working:

On Mac, you'll need `brew install coreutils`, so we can use `gdate`. Otherwise on Linux, it's just `date`. And this function will help you time commands without having to create temporary files or anything:

```
function timeit() {
    start=`gdate +%s%N`
    bash -c $1
    end=`gdate +%s%N`
    runtime=$(((end-start)/1000000000.0))
    echo " seconds"
}
```

And you can use it with a string:

```
timeit 'tsc --noEmit'
```

Comment: I like this solution but I'm more interested in millis. I ported this function to my .bashrc in ubuntu:
```function timeit () {
        start=$(date +%s%N);
        $*;
        end=$(date +%s%N);
        runtime=$(((end-start)/1000000));
        echo "$runtime ms"
}```

Answer (score 3):

When you use GNU AWK since version 4.1, you can load the time library and do:

```
$ awk '@load "time"; BEGIN{printf "%.6f", gettimeofday()}'
```

This will print the current time in seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 in sub second accuracy.

> **`the_time = gettimeofday()`**
>   Return the time in seconds that has elapsed since 1970-01-01 UTC as a floating-point value. If the time is unavailable on this platform, return `-1` and set `ERRNO`. **The returned time should have sub-second precision**, but the actual precision may vary based on the platform. If the standard C `gettimeofday()` system call is available on this platform, then it simply returns the value. Otherwise, if on MS-Windows, it tries to use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Time)</sub>**

On Linux systems, the standard C function `getimeofday()` returns the time in microsecond accuracy.

Comment: specifically GAWK, right? I tried it on regular AWK, and it failed.

Answer (score 3):

I want to generate value from bash and use that value in Java code to convert back to date(java.util).

Following command works for me to generate the value in bash file:

`date +%s000`

Comment: Fine. I recommend we don’t use `java.util.Date`, though. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Then you need just `date %+s` in bash and `Instant.ofEpochSecond()` in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Perl can be used for this, even on exotic platforms like AIX. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

my ($t_sec, $usec) = gettimeofday ();
my $msec= int ($usec/1000);

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
    localtime ($t_sec);

printf "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d %03d\n",
    1900+$year, 1+$mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec, $msec;
```

Answer (score 1):

A Python script like this:

```
import time
cur_time = int(time.time()*1000)
```

Comment: this will not return the number of milliseconds, this will return the number of seconds expressed in milliseconds. Everything will be $SECONDS000

Comment: @kilianc maoyang's Python code is providing milliseconds.

Comment: @jlliagre: But is the actual time resolution better than 16-17 ms (1/60 second) or not?

Comment: Yes, Python's `time.time()` returns a float to 6 decimal places, at least on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

To **print** decimal seconds:

```
start=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000)) \
    && sleep 2 \
    && end=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000)) \
    && runtime=$((end - start))

divisor=1000 \
    && foo=$(printf "%s.%s" $(( runtime / divisor )) $(( runtime % divisor ))) \
    && printf "runtime %s\n" $foo # in bash integer cannot cast to float
```

Output: `runtime 2.3`

Answer (score 0):

To get date in mili-seconds you can use:

```
date +"%T:%N"
```

Comment: `date +"%T:%N"` outputs `11:20:57:N` on macOS 14.2.1. (I couldn't figure out the version of this `date` binary, unfortunately.)

Answer (score -1):

What about using the simple BASH intrinsic variable EPOCHREALTIME?

Comment: This was already recommended in another answer.