# Create timestamp variable in bash script

Tags: bash, variables, timestamp

I am trying to create a timestamp variable in a shell script to make the logging a little easier. I want to create the variable at the beginning of the script and have it print out the current time whenever I issue `echo $timestamp`. It proving to be more difficult then I thought. Here are some things I've tried:

`timestamp="(date +"%T")"` echo prints out `(date +"%T")`

`timestamp="$(date +"%T")"` echo prints the time when the variable was initialized.

Other things I've tried are just slight variations that didn't work any better. Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: kerfile entrypoint

Answer (score 431, accepted):

In order to get the current timestamp and not the time of when a fixed variable is defined, the trick is to use a function and **not** a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define a timestamp function
timestamp() {
  date +"%T" # current time
}

# do something...
timestamp # print timestamp
# do something else...
timestamp # print another timestamp
# continue...
```

If you don't like the format given by the `%T` specifier you can combine the other time conversion specifiers accepted by `date`.  For GNU `date`, you can find the complete list of these specifiers in the official documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html#Time-conversion-specifiers

Comment: Depending on how you intend to use this, you'll still need to use command substitution: `echo "$(timestamp): something happened"`.

Comment: As for formatting, here is a cut-and-dried set of most frequent formats: http://zxq9.com/archives/795

Comment: For me, I wanted  `date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`

Comment: It would be nice to know why someone thinks this answer is wrong: 6 downvotes, but no one cared to explain why.  By reading the question I really can't see what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: for some reason this didn't give me the timestamp but the current time with ":" in between.

Comment: I think a lot of people arrive at this question looking for a way to generate a unix timestamp (as I have) and find the answer by dchakarov to be more useful even though this answer better addresses the asker's question.

Comment: @erikbwork or whoever wants the unix timestamp just simply use `date +%s`

Comment: @KimballRobinson Instead of `%Y-%m-%d`, you can simply use `%F`

Answer (score 796):

If you want to get unix timestamp, then you need to use:

```
timestamp=$(date +%s)
```

`%T` will give you just the time; same as `%H:%M:%S` (via http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/)

Comment: But this variable will just hold the value of the time when the variable was initiated, am I right?

Comment: I guess this is getting a lot of upvotes because it answers the title of the question, but it is not answering the question body : D OP wanted to get a different timestamp every time, whereas this will store one for the whole script.

Comment: I came here looking for this exactly. I.e. the proper format string to get a unix timestamp from `date`. However, I also upvoted the "correct" answer. I wasn't looking for that, but it's a better answer to the original question and it's also really useful to me.

Comment: Worked fine me after prepending 'shell`
`timestamp=$(shell date +%s)`

Comment: @fedorqui so what hinders op to just re-initialize the variable each time?

Answer (score 245):

You can refer to the following table to generate timestamps in various formats:

| Format / result | Command | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YYYY-MM-DD | `date -I` | `$(date -I)` |
| YYYY-MM-DD_hh:mm:ss | `date +%F_%T` | `$(date +%F_%T)` |
| YYYYMMDD_hhmmss | `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S` | `$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)` |
| YYYYMMDD_hhmmss (UTC version) | `date --utc +%Y%m%d_%H%M%SZ` | `$(date --utc +%Y%m%d_%H%M%SZ)` |
| YYYYMMDD_hhmmss (with local TZ) | `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%Z` | `$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%Z)` |
| YYYYMMSShhmmss | `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` | `$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)` |
| YYYYMMSShhmmssnnnnnnnnn | `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N` | `$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N)` |
| YYMMDD_hhmmss | `date +%y%m%d_%H%M%S` | `$(date +%y%m%d_%H%M%S)` |
| Seconds since UNIX epoch | `date +%s` | `$(date +%s)` |
| Nanoseconds only | `date +%N` | `$(date +%N)` |
| Nanoseconds since UNIX epoch | `date +%s%N` | `$(date +%s%N)` |
| ISO8601 UTC timestamp | `date --utc +%FT%TZ` | `$(date --utc +%FT%TZ)` |
| ISO8601 UTC timestamp + ms | `date --utc +%FT%T.%3NZ` | `$(date --utc +%FT%T.%3NZ)` |
| ISO8601 Local TZ timestamp | `date +%FT%T%Z` | `$(date +%FT%T%Z)` |
| YYYY-MM-DD (Short day) | `date +%F\(%a\)` | `$(date +%F\(%a\))` |
| YYYY-MM-DD (Long day) | `date +%F\(%A\)` | `$(date +%F\(%A\))` |

Comment: Not often do I have to scroll through 11 other answers to find the best one. :)

Comment: Pay attention to`date -I`, it does not work on macos bash or zsh. Nevertheless very useful answer.

Comment: $(date +%F) $(date +%T) if you don't want the underscore between date and time

Answer (score 113):

```
DATE=`date "+%Y%m%d"`

DATE_WITH_TIME=`date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"` #add %3N as we want millisecond too
```

Comment: +1 for adding the millisecond part. This `echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3N%z")` 

However I can't get it to work in a Mac terminal. How to do the same in Mac. Thanks

Comment: @kosgeinsky I installed GNU date via `brew install coreutils` and then use `gdate` instead of `date`

Answer (score 82):

ISO 8601 format (`2018-12-23T12:34:56`) is more readable than UNIX timestamp. However on some OSs you cannot have `:` in the filenames. Therefore I recommend using something like this instead:

```
2018-12-23_12-34-56
```

You can use the following command to get the timestamp in this format:

```
TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
```

This is the format I have seen many applications use. Another nice thing about this is that if your file names start with this, you can sort them alphabetically and they would be sorted by date.

Comment: `TZ=UTC date +...` can make this more portable by using UTC timestamp

Comment: Incorporating @MichaelChirico's comment and adding a *Zulu time* (== UTC) `Z` at the end; and modifying @Caner's to use `T`: `TIMESTAMP="$(TZ=UTC date +%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%SZ)"`

Answer (score 36):

And for my fellow Europeans, try using this:

```
timestamp=$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)
```

will give a format of the format: "15-02-2020_19-21-58"

You call the variable and get the string representation like this

```
$timestamp
```

Comment: Please consider using the code notation for your code.

Comment: or a universal solution:   `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` - and thank you for your answer.

Comment: As a European, I've never used `DD-MM-YYYY` in my life, always `YYYY-MM-DD` for everything. That is different from writing "22nd June 2022" in a document, but numerically its never "22-06-2022", its always "2022-06-22". Just saying.

Comment: Good for you :-)

Answer (score 25):

A lot of answers but I couldn't find what I was looking for :

```
date +"%s.%3N"
```

returns something like : `1606297368.210`

Comment: On MacOS the built-in `date` doesn't support the `%N` format; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641565/1677912.

Comment: Yes, lots of answers, most of which are wrong because people apparently didn't read the question

Comment: This works and I wonder what's the meaning of symbol `N`

Comment: They say "Nanoseconds", makes sense: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400542/3322400

Comment: was looking for this, simple and effective

Answer (score 21):

Use command substitution:

```
timestamp=$( date +%T )
```

Comment: This is what I already tried and it only prints out the time when the variable was initialized.

Comment: @dan08: That's how variables work. Use a function if you want dynamic output.

Answer (score 19):

I am using ubuntu 14.04.

The correct way in my system should be `date +%s`.

The output of `date +%T` is like `12:25:25`.

Comment: Hem no: Under Ubuntu 14.04, bash is in version 4.3. [*Correct way should be* `printf -v varname '%(%s)T' -1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74938444/1765658)

Answer (score 15):

You can use

```
timestamp=`date --rfc-3339=seconds`
```

This delivers in the format `2014-02-01 15:12:35-05:00`

The back-tick (`` ` ``) characters will cause what is between them to be evaluated and have the result included in the line.  `date --help` has other options.

Comment: As for what time it gets, this should be executed immediately before inclusion in screen output or a log file intended to have the time of the output listed.

Comment: this is less than ideal format for a timestamp because of the space in the output.  Be sure to quote it "$timestamp" in usage or you will get two params to the command. e.g. `touch $timestamp` will produce two files.

Comment: For those wanting to customize this to remove the space, `date --rfc-3339=...` is (roughly?) equivalent to `date '+%F %T%:z'`, so removing the space is simply (eg): `date '+%F_%T%:z'`

Answer (score 15):

Recent versions of `bash` don't require call to the external program `date`:

```
printf -v timestamp '%(%T)T'
```

`%(...)T` uses the corresponding argument as a UNIX timestamp, and formats it according to the `strftime`-style format between the parentheses. An argument of `-1` corresponds to the current time, and when no ambiguity would occur can be omitted.

Answer (score 8):

## `bash` can show time in microseconds *natively*!

### 1. Avoid forks!!!

Having to run `date` for each logged line is overkill!!

Prefer to use bash's builtins whenever possible.

At time this question was asked, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version was bash-4.2.

In this version, the **pure bash way** for printing current time is:

```
printf '%(%T)T\n' -1
```

or

```
printf '%(%T)T\n' -1
```

So a short function login each lines with timestamp could be:

```
logLine() {
    printf '%(%T)T %s\n' -1 "$*"
}
```

Then

```
$ logLine Hello world.
10:11:32 Hello world.
```

### 2. Time in seconds, using `printf` builtin:

For storing current time into a variable, you will use:

```
printf -v varname '%(%T)T' -1
```

or to store (reusable) *UNIX EPOCH*:

```
printf -v varname '%(%s)T' -1
```

Then

```
printf 'Stored time stamp is: %(%c)T\n' "$varname"
Stored time stamp is: Sat Jan 27 04:26:00 2018
```

#### 2.1 Time in seconds, using `$EPOCHSECONDS` pseudo variable

From version 5.0-alpha of bash, (2018-05-22) we could use two *pseudo* variables: `$EPOCHSECONDS` and `$EPOCHREALTIME`:

```bash
man -P'less +/EPOCH' bash
```

> ```
> EPOCHREALTIME
>        Each time this parameter is referenced, it expands to the number
>        of  seconds  since  the  Unix  Epoch (see time(3)) as a floating
>        point  value  with  micro-second  granularity.   Assignments  to
>        EPOCHREALTIME  are ignored.  If EPOCHREALTIME is unset, it loses
>        its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.
> EPOCHSECONDS
>        Each time this parameter is referenced, it expands to the number
>        of  seconds  since the Unix Epoch (see time(3)).  Assignments to
>        EPOCHSECONDS are ignored.  If EPOCHSECONDS is  unset,  it  loses
>        its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.
> ```

```bash
echo $EPOCHSECONDS
1692818546
myvar=$EPOCHSECONDS
echo $myvar
1692818547
```

Sample: Sleep until next minute

```bash
sleep $((60-EPOCHSECONDS%60));printf '%(%T)T\n' -1
21:26:00
```

### 3. EPOCH time expansion.

The native [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s printf could expand *`UNIX EPOCH SECONDS`* by the classic `date` rules. See: `man -P'less +/^\ *FORMAT' date` or have a look at [Instein's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400542/1765658).

```bash
printf '%(%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M)T\n' $EPOCHSECONDS
Friday 24 November 2023, 09:21
```

With the big advantage of avoiding fork to set variable:

```bash
printf -v renderedTime '%(%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M)T' $EPOCHSECONDS
declare -p renderedTime
```

```
declare -- renderedTime="Friday 24 November 2023, 09:22"
```

### 4. About microseconds

Today, I use *bash >= 5.1.4*...

From version 5.0-alpha of bash, (2018-05-22):

> b. There is an EPOCHSECONDS variable, which expands to the time in seconds
> since the Unix epoch.
>
> c. There is an EPOCHREALTIME variable, which expands to the time in seconds
> since the Unix epoch with microsecond granularity.

So if you want to use microsecond granularity, function could become:

```bash
logLine() {
    local now=$EPOCHREALTIME
    printf '%(%T)T.%s %s\n' ${now%.*} ${now#*.} "$*"
}
```

Then

```bash
$ logLine Hello world.
10:15:56.862732 Hello world.
```

Sleep until next minute become a little more complex as [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) can't compute *real* numbers:

```bash
slptim=00000$((60000000-${EPOCHREALTIME/.}%60000000));\
  printf -v slptim %.6f ${slptim::-6}.${slptim: -6};\
  sleep $slptim;\
  now=${EPOCHREALTIME};\
  printf '%(%H:%M)T:%06.3f\n' ${now%.*} $((${now%.*}%60)).${now#*.}
21:44:00.001
```

#### Storing `$EPOCHREALTIME` before use them

**Important:** But care! _**both variables are not** expanded in **same** way!! See: [Don't mix EPOCHREALTIME and EPOCHSECONDS!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557346/1765658)

And **Avoid** to expand `$EPOCHREALTIME` two times for separating *integer* and *fractional* part:

Don't do this:

```bash
nowSec=${EPOCHREALTIME%.*}
nowMus=${EPOCHREALTIME#*.}
```

But ensure expanding `$EPOCHREALTIME` only once and split them simultaneously:

```bash
IFS=. read nowSec nowMus <<<"$EPOCHREALTIME"
```

So you could:

```
printf '%(%a %d %T)T.%s\n' $nowSec $nowMus
Fri 24 09:31:00.166914
```

Or even to reduce number or decimal:

```
printf -v nowMus %.3f .$nowMus
printf '%(%a %d %T)T.%s\n' $nowSec ${nowMus#*.}
Fri 24 09:31:00.167
```

Answer (score 7):

A timestamp formatting trick for GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
 echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%6N) Info >>> enter main"
```

output:

```
 2023-01-08_23:08:48.013592 Info >>> enter main
```

If you want to replace '_' with a space, do the following (w/o '\' got error message)

```
 echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S.%6N) Info >>> enter main"
 echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %T.%6N) Info >>> enter main"
```

output:

```
 2023-01-08 23:10:40.692674 Info >>> enter main
```

Answer (score 5):

```
timestamp=$(awk 'BEGIN {srand(); print srand()}')
```

srand without a value uses the current timestamp with most Awk implementations.

Comment: fwiw, being curious about the performance: the following print the same: (1) `awk '....'` (as shown above); (2) `date '+%s'`; (3)  `printf '%(%s)T'`; listed in order of increasing performance: on my system, `date` is roughly 2x faster than `awk`; and `printf` is over 50x faster than `date` & 100x faster than `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with following comands.

For timestamp with seconds: `checkDate=$(date "+%s")`

For formated date: `checkDate=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 2):

This is a little more than you asked, so you can customize it to your needs.

> I am trying to create a timestamp variable in a shell script...

This script will allow you to create a variable. Though I'm not entirely sure how reusable is when changing the shell context. But it will do the job.

```
function timestamp {
    TEXT="Date:"
    DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
    TIME=`date +%H:%M:%S`
    ZONE=`date +"%Z %z"`
    echo $TEXT $DATE $TIME $ZONE
}

function fulldate {
  timevariable=$(timestamp)
  echo $timevariable
}

echo "- Output 1:"
timestamp
echo "- Output 2:"
fulldate
echo "- Output 3:"
echo $timevariable
```

Outputs:

```
- Output 1:
Date: 2021-08-12 23:28:08 UTC +0000
- Output 2:
Date: 2021-08-12 23:28:08 UTC +0000
- Output 3:
Date: 2021-08-12 23:28:08 UTC +0000
```

I've tested this working on GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)

Answer (score 2):

If performance is a concern, @chepner's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54054553/965593) is a clear winner.

With a bit more complexity, you can also get micro- or milli- second granularity using only bash built-ins. Below is an example of a function that emits the current timestamp including milliseconds:

```
timestamp() {
    IFS=. read S US <<<$EPOCHREALTIME # Read epoch seconds/microseconds
    MS=$((10#$US/1000)) # Convert to milliseconds (interpret in base-10, even with leading 0)
    printf '%(%F %T)T.%03i' $S $MS # Emit formatted timestamp
}

TS=$(timestamp) # Invoke function, assign to variable
```

Note that the `printf` format can be adjusted emit your preferred date/time format.

Answer (score -1):

The following will give local date and time - it does require internet access however. Depending on what is being logged, this could be beneficial - monitoring and logging connection status?

```
curl -i --silent https://google.com/ 2>&1 | grep date

date: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 17:39:19 GMT
```