# How to change the filename of pytest-html's generated HTML report?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I know how to change the report name, the following does that for me just fine:

```
conftest.py

def pytest_html_report_title(report):
   report.title = 'My API Testing'
```

But that doesn't change the name of the actual file itself.  It is still showing up as `report.html` and just overwriting itself every run.

Is there a way to change the filename?  I want to name it something dynamic with a timestamp so it doesn't keep overwriting the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pytest-html` plugin adds an `--html` CLI option to `pytest` to customize the path and filename of the generated HTML file:

```bash
$ ls | grep -c "html"
0
 
$ pytest --html=mycustomreportfilename.html tests/*
...
- Generated html report: file:/path/to/mycustomreportfilename.html -

$ ls | grep -c "html"
1

$ ls | grep "html"
mycustomreportfilename.html
```

If you want "*something dynamic with a timestamp*" and you are using a shell or an environment that has date/time commands or utilities (such as the [`date` command on Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1401482/2745495)), you can then pass the output of those commands or utilities to the `--html` option (see this [related post on generating various formats using `date`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400542/2745495)):

```bash
$ ls | grep -c "html"
0

$ pytest --html="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%SZ)_report.html" tests/*
$ pytest --html="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%SZ)_report.html" tests/*
$ pytest --html="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%SZ)_report.html" tests/*

$ ls | grep -c "html"
3

$ ls | grep "html"
20240106_171151Z_report.html
20240106_171202Z_report.html
20240106_171206Z_report.html
```

But in doing that, it generates the same `assets` folder for *all* the generated HTML reports. Not sure if that will be a problem, but to guarantee that each report is independent, I suggest also passing the `--self-contained-html` option to [create a self-contained HTML report](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#creating-a-self-contained-report):

```bash
$ pytest --html="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%SZ)_report.html" --self-contained-html tests/*
```

The `--html` option isn't documented in the [pytest-html docs](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (as of pytest-html 4.1.1), but it is there in the source code (again as of pytest-html 4.1.1 https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/blob/4.1.1/src/pytest_html/plugin.py#L27-L33):

```py
group.addoption(
    "--html",
    action="store",
    dest="htmlpath",
    metavar="path",
    default=None,
    help="create html report file at given path.",
)
```