# convert log4j timestamp to millisecond through unix command

Tags: perl, unix

with out using any perl module  (POSIX MKTIME) can it be possible to convert the log4jtime stamp to millisecond or any shell command

**2014-03-12 18:11:47,075** INFO   BAS_Connector-thread-2
I want to convert 2014-03-12 18:11:47,075 =>millisecond

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/linux-command-to-get-time-in-milliseconds
You will get the millisenconds with reference to epoch number

Comment: Why "without any perl module"? Are you asking a homework question? Seems unlikely.
Are you afraid of them? Are you aware that POSIX::mktime is a core builtin and thus you can always rely on it existing?

Answer (score 0):

```
    date --date="2014-03-12 18:11:47,075" +%s --> will convert the given date string to epoch number
    date --date="2014-03-12 18:11:47,075" +%s%N --> in Nanoseconds
    1394662307075000000
    date --date="2014-03-12 18:11:47,075" +%s%3N --> in milliseconds
    1394662307075
```

to covert this to milliseconds,check this SO post: [Linux command to get time in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/linux-command-to-get-time-in-milliseconds)