# Isolate randomness of a local environment from the global R process

Tags: r, random, random-seed

We can use `set.seed()` to set a random seed in R, and this has a global effect. Here is a minimal example to illustrate my goal:

```
set.seed(0)
runif(1)
# [1] 0.8966972

set.seed(0)
f <- function() {
  # I do not want this random number to be affected by the global seed
  runif(1)
}
f()
# [1] 0.8966972
```

Basically I want to be able to avoid the effect of the global random seed (i.e., `.Random.seed`) in a local environment, such as an R function, so that I can achieve some sort of randomness over which the user has no control. For example, even if the user has `set.seed()`, he will still get different output every time he calls this function.

Now there are two implementations. The first one relies on `set.seed(NULL)` to let R re-initialize the random seed every time I want to get some random numbers:

```
createUniqueId <- function(bytes) {
  withPrivateSeed(
    paste(as.hexmode(sample(256, bytes, replace = TRUE) - 1), collapse = "")
  )
}
withPrivateSeed <- function(expr, seed = NULL) {
  oldSeed <- if (exists('.Random.seed', envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)) {
    get('.Random.seed', envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)
  }
  if (!is.null(oldSeed)) {
    on.exit(assign('.Random.seed', oldSeed, envir = .GlobalEnv), add = TRUE)
  }
  set.seed(seed)
  expr
}
```

You can see I get different id strings even if I set the seed to 0, and the global random number stream is still reproducible:

```
> set.seed(0)
> runif(3)
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239
> createUniqueId(4)
[1] "83a18600"
> runif(3)
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819

> set.seed(0)
> runif(3)  # same
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239
> createUniqueId(4)  # different
[1] "77cb3d91"
> runif(3)
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819

> set.seed(0)
> runif(3)
[1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239
> createUniqueId(4)
[1] "c41d61d8"
> runif(3)
[1] 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819
```

The second implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/434/files) on Github. It is more complicated, and the basic idea is:

- initialize the random seed during package startup using `set.seed(NULL)` (in `.onLoad()`)
- store the random seed in a separate environment (`.globals$ownSeed`)
- each time when we want to generate random numbers:

  1. assign the local seed to the global random seed
  2. generate random numbers
  3. assign the new global seed (it has changed due to step 2) to the local seed
  4. restore the global seed to its original value

Now my question is if the two approaches are equivalent in theory. The randomness of first approach relies on the current time and process ID when `createUniqueId()` is called, and the second approach seems to rely on the time and process ID when the package is loaded. For the first approach, is it possible that two calls of `createUniqueId()` happen exactly at the same time in the same R process so that they return the same id string?

### Update

In the answer below, Robert Krzyzanowski provided some empirical evidence that `set.seed(NULL)` can lead to serious ID collisions. I did a [simple visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2teJA.png) for it:

```
createGlobalUniqueId <- function(bytes) {
  paste(as.hexmode(sample(256, bytes, replace = TRUE) - 1), collapse = "")
}
n <- 10000
length(unique(replicate(n, createGlobalUniqueId(5))))
length(unique(x <- replicate(n, createUniqueId(5))))
# denote duplicated values by 1, and unique ones by 0
png('rng-time.png', width = 4000, height = 400)
par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1), xaxs = 'i')
plot(1:n, duplicated(x), type = 'l')
dev.off()
```

[image: random numbers from set.seed(NULL)]

When the line reaches the top of the plot, that means there is a duplicate value generated. However, note these duplicates do not come successively, i.e. `any(x[-1] == x[-n])` is normally `FALSE`. There might be a pattern for the duplication associated with the system time. I'm not able to investigate further due to my lack of understanding of how the time-based random seed works, but you can see the relevant pieces of C source code [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5b6690cb7d1b459cb0610706b2feec96184c038c/src/main/times.c#L149) and [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/da62cf194897d5fe035affa6f88d96f36a18fcda/src/main/RNG.c#L526).

Comment: [You can seed using system time.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728422/how-do-i-stop-set-seed-after-a-specific-line-of-code/22728459#22728459)

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski I mentioned `set.seed(NULL)` in the post, which does what you suggested, and is actually even better, since it makes use of the process ID as well. I think this should be the answer of the post that you linked to. The question is whether the two approaches differ in theory.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I made to my answer, it has interesting conclusions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought it would be nice to have just an independent RNG inside your function, that is not affected by the global seed, but would have its own seed. Turns out, `randtoolbox` offers this functionality:

```
library(randtoolbox)
replicate(3, {
  set.seed(1)
  c(runif(1), WELL(3), runif(1))
})   
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.265508663 0.2655087 0.2655087
#[2,] 0.481195594 0.3999952 0.9474923
#[3,] 0.003865934 0.6596869 0.4684255
#[4,] 0.484556709 0.9923884 0.1153879
#[5,] 0.372123900 0.3721239 0.3721239
```

Top and bottom rows are affected by the seed, whereas middle ones are "truly random".

Based on that, here's the implementation of your function:

```
sample_WELL <- function(n, size=n) {
  findInterval(WELL(size), 0:n/n)
}

createUniqueId_WELL <- function(bytes) {
  paste(as.hexmode(sample_WELL(256, bytes) - 1), collapse = "")
}

length(unique(replicate(10000, createUniqueId_WELL(5))))
#[1] 10000

# independency on the seed: 
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(100, createGlobalUniqueId(5))
x_WELL <- replicate(100, createUniqueId_WELL(5))
set.seed(1)
y <- replicate(100, createGlobalUniqueId(5))
y_WELL <- replicate(100, createUniqueId_WELL(5))
sum(x==y)
#[1] 100
sum(x_WELL==y_WELL)
#[1] 0
```

**Edit**

To understand why we get duplicated keys, we should take a look what happens when we call `set.seed(NULL)`. All RNG-related code is written in C, so we should go directly to [svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/RNG.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/RNG.c) and refer to the function `do_setseed`. If `seed = NULL` then clearly `TimeToSeed` is called. There's a comment that states it should be located in datetime.c, however, it can be found in [svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/times.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/times.c).

Navigating the R source can be difficult, so I'm pasting the function here:

```
/* For RNG.c, main.c, mkdtemp.c */
attribute_hidden
unsigned int TimeToSeed(void)
{
    unsigned int seed, pid = getpid();
#if defined(HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME) && defined(CLOCK_REALTIME)
    {
    struct timespec tp;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
    seed = (unsigned int)(((uint_least64_t) tp.tv_nsec << 16) ^ tp.tv_sec);
    }
#elif defined(HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY)
    {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
    seed = (unsigned int)(((uint_least64_t) tv.tv_usec << 16) ^ tv.tv_sec);
    }
#else
    /* C89, so must work */
    seed = (Int32) time(NULL);
#endif
    seed ^= (pid <<16);
    return seed;
}
```

So each time we call `set.seed(NULL)`, R does these steps:

1. Takes current time in seconds and nanoseconds (if possible, platform dependency here in `#if defined` blocks)
2. Applies bit shift to nanoseconds and bit 'xor'es result with seconds
3. Applies bit shift to pid and bit 'xor'es it with the previous result
4. Sets the result as a new seed

Well, now it's almost obvious that we get duplicated values when the resulting seeds collide. My guess is this happens when two calls fall within 1 second, so that tv_sec is constant. To confirm that, I'm introducing a lag:

```
createUniqueIdWithLag <- function(bytes, lag) {
  Sys.sleep(lag)
  createUniqueId(bytes)
}
lags <- 1 / 10 ^ (1:5)
sapply(lags, function(x) length(unique(replicate(n, createUniqueIdWithLag(5, x)))))
[1] 1000 1000  996  992  990
```

What's confusing is that even the lag is substantial compared to nanoseconds, we still get collisions! Let's dig it further then, I wrote a "debugging emulator" for the seed:

```
emulate_seed <- function() {
  tv <- as.numeric(system('echo $(($(date +%s%N)))', intern = TRUE))
  pid <- Sys.getpid()
  tv_nsec <- tv %% 1e9
  tv_sec <- tv %/% 1e9
  seed <- bitwXor(bitwShiftL(tv_nsec, 16), tv_sec)
  seed <- bitwXor(bitwShiftL(pid, 16), seed)
  c(seed, tv_nsec, tv_sec, pid)
}

z <- replicate(1000, emulate_seed())
sapply(1:4, function(i) length(unique(z[i, ])))
# unique seeds, nanosecs, secs, pids:
#[1]  941 1000   36    1
```

That is really confusing: nanoseconds are all unique, and that does not guarantee uniqueness of the final seed. To demonstrate that effect, here's one of the duplicates:

```
#            [,1]        [,2] 
#[1,] -1654969360 -1654969360
#[2,]   135644672   962643456
#[3,]  1397894128  1397894128 
#[4,]        2057        2057
bitwShiftL(135644672, 16)
#[1] -973078528
bitwShiftL(962643456, 16)
#[1] -973078528
```

The final note: the binary representation of these two numbers and the shift is

```
00001000000101011100011000000000 << 16 => 1100011000000000 + 16 zeroes
00111001011000001100011000000000 << 16 => 1100011000000000 + 16 zeroes
```

So yes, this is really an unwanted collision.

Well, after all that, the final conclusion is: `set.seed(NULL)` is vulnerable to high load and does not guarantee the absence of collisions when dealing with multiple consecutive calls!

Comment: Yep, now I know a separate seed is good, and my question boils down to how a random number is generated from the time stamp and process id, and how to explain the duplicate values.

Answer (score 4):

For the first approach, it does indeed seem to be possible that two calls of `createUniqueId()` happen at exactly the same time in the same R process and return the same ID string.

```
length(unique(sapply(seq_len(100000), function(.) createUniqueId(5))))
# [1] 93906
createGlobalUniqueId <- function(bytes) paste(as.hexmode(sample(256, bytes, replace = TRUE) - 1), collapse = "")
length(unique(sapply(seq_len(100000), function(.) createGlobalUniqueId(5))))
# [1] 100000
```

Therefore, I would go with the second approach if you do not want ID collisions.

Comment: Thanks for the empirical evidence! I just updated my post. BTW, `sapply(seq_len(n), function(.) expr)` is basically `replicate(n, expr)`.