# bash - convert date time into compatible format for kibana

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, datetime-format, kibana

I'm using elasticsearch REST API to add some data to be used in kibana dashboard.
I have time stamps in this format **2015-08-04 10:13:14**. This format seems to be incompatible with kibana.

Is there any way to convert it to something like logstash timestamps (2015-08-04T10:13:14.000Z) or any other solution to get kibana work on this?

Comment: Are the input timestamps in Zulu (UTC, GMT) time?  Or are they in a local time?  Your required output suggests that they're in Zulu time already, which greatly simplifies life — a simple textual transform is all that's necessary.  Kibana seems to be a trifle fussy, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with bash one whitespace by `T` and append `.000Z`:

```
a="2015-08-04 10:13:14"
b="${a/ /T}.000Z"
echo "$b"
```

Output:

```
2015-08-04T10:13:14.000Z
```

Answer (score 7):

you can get the exact miliseconds by using:

```
timestamp=`date +"%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3N"`
```

As seen in [Linux command to get time in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704121/590247):

> - `date +"%T.%N"` returns the current time with nanoseconds.
> - `date +"%T.%6N"` returns the current time with nanoseconds rounded to the first 6 digits, which is microseconds.
> - `date +"%T.%3N"` returns the current time with nanoseconds rounded to the first 3 digits, which is milliseconds.