# /usr/bin/time --format output elapsed time in milliseconds

Tags: bash, time, debian, time-format

I use the /usr/bin/time program to measure the time for a command.
with the --format parameter i can format the output.
e.g.

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" ls
```

is there a way to output a bigger accuracy of the elapsed seconds? or just output milliseconds, not seconds?

In the manual of /usr/bin/time it only says something about seconds, but maybe there is a way and someone can help me...
thanks!

**EDIT**:
I know about the bash command "time" which uses the format of the environment variable "TIMEFORMAT". sorry, but i don't wanna change that env-var... seems to risky to me, solution should be something that doesn't change the running system at all :)

Comment: The man page says nothing about that. So I assume that it is not possible using an *unchanged* version of time. It should be possible to craft a patch for the output format, but I don't know whether it is possible to get a higher accuracy.

Comment: Just pointing out for future readers that the `TIMEFORMAT` variable is _only_ used for controlling the output of the builtin `time` command. There's no risk associated with changing it.

Comment: Also changes to a shell only affect that shell.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `date` command:

```
ts=$(date +%s%N) ; my_command ; tt=$((($(date +%s%N) - $ts)/1000000)) ; echo "Time taken: $tt milliseconds"
```

`%N` [should return *nanoseconds*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html#DATECALC), and 1 millisecond is 1000000 nanosecond, hence by division would return the time taken to execute `my_command` in milliseconds.

**NOTE** that the  `%N` [is not supported on all systems, but most of them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804966/date-command-does-not-follow-linux-specifications-mac-os-x-lion)

Comment: excelent, accepted! didn't think of date, but that's good enough! To get from nanoseconds to milliseconds you have to divide by 1000000, though: ts=$(date +%s%N) ; sleep 1 ; tt=$((($(date +%s%N) - $ts)/1000000)) ; echo $tt

Comment: For those on OSX without the required temporal resolution from date, one can substitute the native date with gdate.

For example: 

`brew install coreutils` if necessary and then

`ts=$(gdate +%s%N) ; sleep 1 ; tt=$((($(gdate +%s%N) - $ts)/1000000)) ; echo $tt`

[source](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135742/time-in-milliseconds-since-epoch-in-the-terminal)

Comment: You can use %3N on systems that have %N to get just the milliseconds. See `https://serverfault.com/a/588705/432437`

Answer (score 11):

For convenience I made devnull's answer into a script (I named it millisecond-time).

```
#!/bin/bash
ts=$(date +%s%N) ; $@ ; tt=$((($(date +%s%N) - $ts)/1000000)) ; echo "Time taken: $tt milliseconds"
```

I put the script in `/usr/local/bin`.
Gave it execute rights `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/millisecond-time`.
Now I can use it like this: `millisecond-time my_command`

P.s. This would be a comment if I had the rep'.

Comment: To allow `my_command` to have arguments, you may want to surround the provided command in quotes: `"$@"`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things getting confused in this thread.

Bash has a built-in `time` command which supports a `TIMEFORMAT` environment variable that will let you format the output. For details on this run `man bash` and search for `TIMEFORMAT`.

There is also a standard `/usr/bin/time` command-line utility which supports a `TIME` environment variable that will let you format the output (or you can use `-f` or `--format` on the command line). For details on this run `man time` and search for `TIME`.

If you want the number of seconds the command took to run you can either use the built-in bash command (which supports a maximum precision of three decimal places):

```
bash# export TIMEFORMAT="%3lR" 
bash# time find /etc > /dev/null
0m0.015s
```

Or you can use the command-line utility (which supports a maximum precision of two decimal places):

```
shell# export TIME="%E"
shell# /usr/bin/time find /opt/ > /dev/null
0:00.72
```

As mentioned above neither of these variables are used by anything else and are safe to change.