# How to push a file to past time?

Tags: git, github

Yesterday, I made changes on a project file but forgot to commit and push it on github. I don't want that my contribution streak breaks after 51 days..so I would like to push that commit to yesterday so that my streak keeps on... Is that possible?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have that script in my path, called **[`git-rcd`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/b7c1d6c48d76859605f4a06896e0e1f797656c82/sbin/git-rcd)**, which changes `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` of any commit you want (not just the last one)

```
#!/bin/bash
# commit
# date YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS

commit="$1" datecal="$2"
temp_branch="temp-rebasing-branch"
current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

date_timestamp=$(date -d "$datecal" +%s)
date_r=$(date -R -d "$datecal")
echo "datecal=$datecal => date_timestamp=$date_timestamp date_r=$date_r"

if [[ -z "$commit" ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

git checkout -b "$temp_branch" "$commit"
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$date_timestamp" GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$date_timestamp" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "$date_r"
git checkout "$current_branch"
git rebase --autostash --committer-date-is-author-date "$commit" --onto "$temp_branch"
git branch -d "$temp_branch"
```

What that allows me is take the last commit I just did and type:

```
git rcd @ '1 day ago'
```

And presto! My last commit has now been done yesterday.

It changes any commit you want:

```
git rcd @~2 '1 day ago'
```

That would only change the `HEAD~2` (and not the `HEAD~` or `HEAD`)

The script works even on Windows.

Once the change is done, push (or `git push --force` if you pushed before with the wrong date). And your streak is preserved.

---

Note (2020), [David Fullerton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91687/david-fullerton) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722637/how-to-push-a-file-to-past-time/24722927#comment108769784_24722927):

> Getting this working on Mac OS X required:
>
> - [installing coreutils to get GNU `date`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9804966/6309) and then
> - updating the script to use `gdate`

Comment: How can I add this script to my path and utilize this? Do you have any documentation/readme on this?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 create a file named `git-rcd` (no extension) and put it anywhere in your `PATH` (meaning in one of the folders listed by the environment variable `PATH`). Then the command `rcd` will be known by `git`: `git rcd` will work.

Comment: I receive an error when I try this:

sudo git rcd @ '1 day ago'

fatal: cannot exec 'git-rcd': Permission denied

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 no sudo needed. And make sure the script is executable: `chmod 755`. And that you are using a recen version of git (not some old 1.7.10)

Comment: I got my permissions working so I can run this now. When I run it git throws an error for an invalid date format though. date: illegal option -- R .... fatal: invalid date format:

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 try with double-quotes: `git rcd @ "1 day ago"`

Comment: Getting this working on Mac OS X required [installing coreutils to get GNU date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804966/date-command-does-not-follow-linux-specifications-mac-os-x-lion) and then updating the script to use `gdate`

Comment: @DavidFullerton Thank you for this feedback (and your service to Stack Overflow!). I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

> Yesterday, I made changes on a project file but forgot to commit and push it on github

As far as I know, GitHub contribution graphs rely on commit datetimes, not push datetimes. FWIW, there are even tools abusing this to use the contribution graph as a drawing board (cf. this **[google search](https://www.google.com/#q=draw+github+contribution+graph)**).

So the easy way would be to

- Commit locally now
- Then rewrite your latest commit to change the authorship date (pick the time and timezone you'd like) with something like `git commit --amend --date="Wed Jul 12 14:17 2014 +0900"`
- Push

Comment: `git add newFile.php` and `git commit -m "newFile Update" ` and `git commit --amend --date="Str Jul 12 14:17 2014 +0900" and push it updates the file as contribution of today...

Comment: @user3464303 Awesome!