# Git marking all new commits as occurring "3 months ago"

Tags: git, github

I started a new repo and pushed something to it and my gitlog states that it was created 3 months ago. When I check my github contributions calendar it is listed as being created 3 months ago. All new files I create and commit now are being marked as being committed 3 months ago. How do I reset my git commit date to the current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script in order to change the committer and author date of any git commit:
See "[How to push a file to past time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722927/6309)"

```
git rcd @ "1 hour ago"
```

Check also if you haven't defined, in your current environment variables, `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` or `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`: that would explain why creating a new commit doesn't use the current date.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my naivity but how do I check/set enviroment variables? That actually may be the issue. Thanks again VonC

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 what OS are you using? Try typing `env` or `set`

Comment: Cool got it! I just had to unset those environment variables. Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 good job! Check any environment variable starting with GIT: they can influence how git works.