# GitHub - can I repopulate Contributions chart with missing commits?

Tags: git, commit

I recently noticed that very few of my commits were showing on my Contributions graph even though they were inside of each repository.  After deleting and re-adding my e-mail address my commits are now showing up.

Is there a way to get my older commits (which have to correct e-mail association) to show up on the Contributions graph as well?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** this is possible.  You can modify the `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` variables...

[This project](https://github.com/gelstudios/gitfiti) implements this in Python

Answer (score 2):

Not only you can fill out the gaps, but you really can do whatever you want with those contributions: see [The Fancy Github Contributions - CNTD](http://blog.codehate.com/post/118433666709/the-fancy-github-contributions-cntd)

[image: http://40.media.tumblr.com/a4d8225dda1ece928648acf2ed3050db/tumblr_inline_no10lbF0UG1swdta0_500.png]

Or:

[image: http://40.media.tumblr.com/0947985d722f6717ec76bd283e641034/tumblr_inline_nmbi0m15Yp1swdta0_500.png]

(and you can [view those contributions in 3D now](https://github.com/jasonlong/isometric-contributions))

When I miss a day, I simply rebase a local history of one of my local clone, using git rcd to change the author date of a commit.
See "[How to push a file to past time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722927/6309)".

```
git rcd @~2 '1 day ago'
```

Comment: linkedby https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170859/10579