# grep date ranges from feed

Tags: shell, date, grep, range

I saw it posted here that this would work but it is not working for me. I need something short and sweet like this command. using the python version of rsstail.

`rsstail -dl -e 1 -U -a -u https://threatpost.com/feed/ -n 10 | grep -A 2 "2021/03/15 20[1-5]"`

This should grab the last 5 hours but it doesn't.

Sample line from the feed follows

```
Updated: 2021/03/12 21:42:59  Title: Critical Security Hole Can Knock Smart Meters Offline  Author: Tara Seals  Link: https://threatpost.com/critical-security-smart-meter-offline/164753/   Description: Unpatched Schneider Electric PowerLogic ION/PM smart meters are open to dangerous attacks
```

Comment: Can you share some output from `rsstail` (i.e. drop the grep) ?

Comment: Or indicate what the format of the timestamp is - as the HHMM or HH:MM (or what is it) might not match your regex.  And getting 2 lines after each timestamp - will it give your expect output - please add that.

Comment: ```Updated: 2021/03/12 21:42:59  Title: Critical Security Hole Can Knock Smart Meters Offline  Author: Tara Seals  Link: https://threatpost.com/critical-security-smart-meter-offline/164753/  
Description: Unpatched Schneider Electric PowerLogic ION/PM smart meters are open to dangerous attacks```

Answer (score 0):

You were heading on the right track with the grep - however there wasn't going to be a match on the date because 20[1-5] matches two digits and a digit in the range 1-5 in a row after the specific date - that would match
`2021/03/15 2022` but not `2021/03/15 20:22`.

Assuming you are in daylight hours you don't have to worry about spanning two days - imagine you ran at 2:00am you'd need yesterday 21:XX, 22:XX, 23:XX and today 00:XXam, 01:XXam.

So say you run at 11.am today - previous 5 hours 6/7/8/9/10 .. so you could do something like this.

```
grep -A 2 -E -e '2021/03/17 (06|07|08|09|10):'
```

OR even

```
grep -A 2 -E -e '2021/03/17 (0[6789]|10):'
```

You can auto-generate some of the query like this (again I've ignored cross-over of hour) [NOTE: OSX Date & GNU date are different - this is OSX example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804966/date-command-does-not-follow-linux-specifications-mac-os-x-lion) -

```
FROMMIN=$( date -v -4M +'%M' )
TOMIN=$( date +'%M' )
## GIVES like this 2021/03/17 20:(44|45|46|47|48|)
MATCH=$( echo $( date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:(' )$( seq -s "|" $FROMMIN 1 $TOMIN )')' )
grep -A 2 -E -e "$MATCH"
```